# What are the Open source WYSIWYG Independent Web Equation Editors available on LaTeX/MathML

Tags: equations, editors, mathml

I am looking for a solution of an Equation Editor to be added to my site. The equation editor should be open source, WYSIWYG (users should be able to type out Equations as if in MS Equation Editor or MathType), convert it to LaTeX, store in my database, retrieve as per the command and render in HTML, should be web based where all files reside on my server, and should facilitate editing in WYSIWYG mode at any stage. I wish to integrate with PHP on a Linux Platform. I would like images also be handled by the editor in EPS format.

I have tried many equation editors. These are either requiring knowledge of LaTeX or are online plugins (where the equation is converted to LaTeX on a third party server) or these are windows applications or desktop applications.

Can any one suggest how to proceed and which components to use in which order or share his/her knowledge with us or suggest a professional who can help me, may be, on payment basis. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Two comments: (1) which images and why eps? (2) what do you mean by "the other server"? is it the client?

Comment: Does it need to make an omelet too? :-P I think TinyMCE has the WYSIWYG but not the LaTeX conversion.  MathJAX has the LaTeX rendering but not the input shortcuts.  Those are the only free choices I know of.

Comment: Mathew, that's what we have already tried and that's why this post.  I am looking for a real value product for a input of equations, conversion, storing and rendering on html in a dynamic manner

Comment: Dear Juan, Thanks for your interest. Images would be any diagrams, figures, graphs or images relating to Math or Physics. These can be embedded in Latex by converting them to EPS. Regarding the Other Server, we would like it to reside on our server not a third party server. I definitely don't mean a client.

Comment: I see, it's clearer now. My comment about the images is that perhaps you should perhaps consider using `pdf` rather than `eps` to store them. But on your actual question, it would be very useful to have an editor with the features you describe, sadly, I don't know of any editor that is currently able to do this.

Comment: Dear Juan, using pdf format would rather involve equation numbering for millions of images which would need to be recalled from database and rendered on html with text dynamically. The process has to be fast enough and shall be used simultaneously by a large number of users and rendered dynamically for each user as per his requistion. That's why we thought of using eps format so that by using latex only we can render it on html in a faster manner. EPS is a Post Script and can be combined with Latex. Can you suggest an expert on this who can integrate all this for our company

Comment: I would like to know any update on suBject, since currently we are working something similar to the above requirement.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for something similar and came across this question. Then I was excited to find [Mathquill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor), via the [Wikipedia page on formula editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor).

I've used a bunch of different formula editors, from MS Equation Editor to Google Docs' to LyX, and this is probably the most usable/fluid of all of them for simply banging out formulas. And it's web-based and GPL. This thing is much nicer than Google Docs' formula editor, at least.

Still leaves plenty of things to be desired, e.g. so far I've found: bolding, entering things like bra-kets, \hat, undo/redo history, mouse drag selection, etc. But I'm impressed by what's already in there. Anyway, it's just a few Javascript files, and [on github](https://github.com/laughinghan/mathquill).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if MathMagic is (to be) available on Linux but they offer various output options including LaTeX, MathML, ASCIIMath, JPEG, GIF, and EPS, and others. If supporting multiple file formats(in both importing and exporting) is a concern, MathMagic should be second to none, although their LaTeX support is not perfect.

www.mathmagic.com

If a commercial version or source licensing is an option, you may want to contact them.

Comment: But this looks like a desktop application? The OP was looking for an on-line web editor.

Comment: Thanks Jam for your interest. However, Firstly, as Juan puts it, it's a desktop application not a web based application. Secondly, it's only on mac and windows and is not linux based. Our search still continues...