# WYSIWYG JavaScript editor for MathJax

Tags: editors, mathjax

I am looking for a WYSYWIG JavaScript editor for MathJax. I've read all the answers to similar questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/what-are-the-open-source-wysiwyg-independent-web-equation-editors-available-on-l) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57068/wysiwyg-latex-editor-for-maths)) but could not find anything that is licensed under a liberal open source license (GPL/LGPL is great but not an option for my project), written in JavaScript, and working in WYSIWYG mode (instead of live rendering of LaTeX).

If such a thing does not exist, how would you go about building it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can cetainly say that since doing LaTeX WYSIWYG is very complicated itself and only LyX seems to be close to it, there is surely no such option with the real LaTeX. Remember that systems like MathJaX use only the LaTeX syntax, but their rendering core is completely different.

Notice that LaTeX itself is very complicated and attempts to make it run in JavaScript were unsuccessful.

Comment: Indeed. I should have indicated that I don't need it to support the full LaTeX scope. Supporting the subset currently supported by CodeCogs' editor would be a great start...

Comment: In that case, this is not a question for TeX.SE, and it will be closed. Notice that questions MathJaX and similar systems are considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Feel free to close the question then.

Comment: Sorry for the too strong voice in my previous comment. The problem really is that it seems you seek for an environment implemented in JavaScript, that is able to interpret basic LaTeX instructions and display the result. These systems really share only the syntax with LaTeX, but not the real core. That's the reason why we consider them off-topic here.

Comment: This is probably off topic here, you would be better at the mathjax forum, in particular this thread links to several mathjax based web editors https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/BZeCIvhEpO4

Comment: I didn't realize there was a MathJax forum! These SE guys/girls never stop... Thanks for the tip. I'll go there. And sorry again for the noise.

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi 'Noise' not a problem: for non-experts, the fact that MathJax is not TeX might not be so obvious

Comment: @David, thanks for the link, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ooh maybe I should have made that an answer and stolen the 15pt from @tohecz :-)

Comment: Shall we call LaTeX complicated? :) I'd say it's complex.