# point-and-click open source javascript equation editor for latex?

Tags: equations, editors, javascript

Does anyone have experience with a good open source equation editor for online use?  I'm not interested in WYSIWYG ([What are the Open source WYSIWYG Independent Web Equation Editors available on LaTeX/MathML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/what-are-the-open-source-wysiwyg-independent-web-equation-editors-available-on-l)), just a nice point-and-click solution for inputting things like `$\frac{}{}$` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on topic for the site, since our focus is on using the TeX family of applications, not the broader topic of applications that use TeX-like syntax.  However, if all you want to do is enter LaTeX math code and have it rendered, the MathJax site has a [demo page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/).

Comment: Hi @MatthewLeingang - it's a question about how to enter syntactically-correct TeX into web browsers.  MathJaX is good for displaying the results of that process.  Unfortunately the demo site seems to be down at the moment so I can't check whether they have a nice editor there as well!

Comment: @JoeCorneli: give us something to work with? What are you trying to do here? You tell us you want to be able to input things like your `$\frac{}{}$`, but without knowing _why_, we can't help. Do you want  to produce graphics, covert to another language, or what? Are you looking to have something you can use to test equations? Ah, whatever, I'll try an answer.

Comment: @LostBrit - I am indeed looking for something I can host myself.  The UI from the SciWeavers tool you pointed out is nice, but the tool isn't open source.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want point and click functionality that builds up your latex code for you, try http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor.

Alternatively, if you want to type in the source yourself and see if it compiles, try something like http://www.writelatex.com.

Comment: The sciweavers thing is indeed a lot like what I have in mind, but it's not open source.

Comment: @JoeCorneli in that case, please see my comment to your original question. I definitely don't understand what you are looking for! Are you looking for something you can host yourself? Maybe you could answer that original comment and then people will have a better idea.