# How can I generate some Latex output (equation) to be imported in MS Word?

Tags: msword

Let's say I want to make a document in Microsoft Word (don't asks why), but for the formulas I want to use LaTeX and then paste it as a picture in my word document, how would I go about doing that? I would prefer not to download programs. Is there just a site where you can type something in LaTeX and just copy it as an image? I'm not a computer expert so if it's easy to do yourself I'd like to hear how to.

Sort of like [this](http://mathb.in/) site only with the ability to make it an image.

Comment: There is a Mac utility called [LaTeXit](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) that comes with the [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/) distribution.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I don't have a mac

Comment: Googling "latexit alternative for pc" led me to [this SuperUser post](http://superuser.com/questions/226649/latexit-alternative-for-windows).

Comment: Use an online viewer like www.writelatex.com and make a screen capture then paste in Word.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.

Comment: @MWord Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/embed-latex-math-equations-into-microsoft-word

Comment: The [Online Equation Editor](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) from SciWeavers pointed out to me in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114605/point-and-click-open-source-javascript-equation-editor-for-latex is a lot like what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The standalone document class produces an output that is clipped to the actual object size.  Once you have it as a PDF, perhaps that is directly importable to Word.  If not, a conversion to jpg is possible, externally.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$
y = A x^2 + B x + c
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `standalone` also supports conversion to raster images, provided you have installed the free [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways is probably to go to [this website](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), type the equation and download the image. You can select the type of image you want, resolution, etc. Then just insert the image into word.

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty try installing [LaTeX in Word plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latexinword/). It's an open source development and should allow you to use LaTeX in Word directly. You should check that it's compatible with your version of Word before installing.

Answer (score 0):

If change your mind and decide you want to download something:

1. Michael Kohlhase has an experimental contribution to the LaTeXML project called LaTeX2ODT.  You can read about progress on the project [here](https://trac.mathweb.org/LaTeXML/ticket/1698), or test out the experiment yourself by [downloading and installing the arXMLiv branch](https://github.com/KWARC/planetary/#install-latexml) of LaTeXML.
2. In the [README](https://trac.mathweb.org/LaTeXML/browser/branches/arXMLiv/tools/LaTeX2ODT/README), Michael mentions that "[tex4ht](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) does a good job at converting analogously, but it is supposed to be underdocumented and unstable (but probably has more coverage than my converter)."

Have fun!