# ink Equation in Latex

Tags: equations, editors

We are aware that Microsoft Word has a feature called ink Equation that allows the user to write a formula with a light pen, even if the formula is complex, and then convert it into a real equation with an acceptable font. Obviously, this is an excellent option, since it is not necessary to use multiple commands to write a lengthy equation; instead, one can simply write the equation as seen.

My query is: Is there a latex editor that includes this feature? If the answer is affirmative, which editor has this capability?

Comment: What did you research so far? Please add to your question via EDIT.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could tell me what I should have searched for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the request is for a primer in websearch.

It's an `iterative process`:

- you start somewhere
- you refine your search
- you select best solutions

#### Potential shortcuts

Whatch the right side under `Related`, showing links within this place. E.g. inspecting these lead you to either a solution or: new search terms. `Take notes` and watch the *Related* there, as well ...

[What are the Open source WYSIWYG Independent Web Equation Editors available on LaTeX/MathML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/what-are-the-open-source-wysiwyg-independent-web-equation-editors-available-on-l?rq=1)

[Visual Equation Editor to LaTeX Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18155/visual-equation-editor-to-latex-code?rq=1)

#### Iterations

Start somewhere, e.g. using your title as search term:
[ink Equation in Latex](https://www.google.com/search?q=ink%20Equation%20in%20Latex) . Almost the first entry leads me to [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/equation-to-latex) , which probably is already what you are looking for.

Check out the other links listed from this search term alone.

#### Refinements

- consult your notes, for synonyms, technical terms, nerdy slang etc.
- same for the websites you followed by aboves links
- use the search engines proposals as well, see screenshots
- and of course try *alternative mathpix* and similar as serach term

As is:

[image: ex1]

Reduced/modified:

[image: ex2]

If you are really nerdy:

[image: ex3]

#### Verification

TRY your findings in this sites search box as well, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathpix, which leads to e.g. [Tikz tools like mathpix ？](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501659/tikz-tools-like-mathpix)

#### Using latest technology (with care)

You can try AI, like so. This one seems to compile some own websearches into something presentable:

```
https://www.phind.com

How to find what I want by a websearch?
Answer | gpt-3.5 Model

To find what you want by a web search, you can use filters to narrow down your results. Here are some tips to help you out:

    Use site or domain filters to search for results from a specific website or domain.
    Try filtering results based on where your search terms appear in the page, such as the title, text, or URL.
    Use SafeSearch to remove explicit results.
    Filter by file type to find specific formats like .pdf, .xls, or .ppt.
    Use usage rights to find pages that have license information attached to them.

In addition, you can try using alternative search engines like SearX, which offers unbiased results from several sources and allows for customization and hosting on your own server.
```

Comment: Thanks your guidance is very friutful

Comment: Thanks. Kindly check my latest edit, too.